# Trouble injecting service to HomeController

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, controller

I am trying to inject a service to the homeController and I get this error:
Servlet.init() for servlet mvc-dispatcher threw exception.

I guess that the applicationContext.xml doesn't get loaded ?

Here are my files

homeController:

```
package com.springapp.mvc;
import interfaces.SaleRequestService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {

private SaleRequestService _saleRequestService;

public HelloController(SaleRequestService saleRequestService){
    _saleRequestService = saleRequestService;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!");
    return "hello";
}
}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

   <bean id="saleRequestService" class="services.SaleRequestServiceImpl"/>

   <bean class="com.springapp.mvc.HelloController">
          <constructor-arg index="0" ref="saleRequestService"/>
   </bean>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

stacktrace:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'helloController' defined in file [C:\Dev\hera\hera.web\target\hera.web\WEB-INF\classes\com\springapp\mvc\HelloController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.springapp.mvc.HelloController]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.springapp.mvc.HelloController.()

Comment: Put `@Autowired` on your constructor. Pro tip make your variable `final`.

Comment: I added @Autowired to the HomeController constructor. No difference, still same error

Comment: Well I doubt it is the same error... I guess you are now getting a error stating that there is `no bean found for SaleRequestService...` or something like that. Let me guess, you have a `<context:component-scan />` in your `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` and no `@Service` on your service?

Comment: Also what is `HomeController`? where as the error is about `HelloController`?

Comment: You are right, the error now is: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [interfaces.SaleRequestService]: : No qualifying bean of type [interfaces.SaleRequestService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.

Comment: For starters remove the bean definition for the controller from the `applicationContext.xml` as it should be placed only there. Then either add a `ContextLoaderListener` to make the `applicationContext.xml` have any effect, or simply add the service definition to the `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` or add `@Service` to the class.

Comment: ok, I deleted the applicationContext.xml file, and removed the context-param from web.xml and added this <bean id="saleRequestService" class="services.SaleRequestServiceImpl"/> to the dispatcher-servlet